# junitreport : xslt fails with StackOverflowError when there are many newlines/linefeeds

Tags: java, xslt, ant, junit

I am using ant 1.8.2. Let us say a test fails with stackoverflow error.

```
import junit.framework.TestCase;

 /**a failing test */
 public class FailingTest    extends TestCase
 {

    public void testFail() {
        testFail();// gives stackoverflow- result xml is now a large document
    }
 }
```

Running junitreport will fail with below error

> [junitreport] jar:file://lib/ant-junit.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/optional/junit/xsl/junit-frames.xsl:65:57:
>   Fatal Error! java.lang.StackOverflowError Cause:
>   java.lang.StackOverflowError

The reason seems to be large  text content in Test result XML file.

```
 <testcase classname="chs.FailingTest" name="testFail" time="0.012">
      <error type="java.lang.StackOverflowError">java.lang.StackOverflowError
          at chs.FailingTest.testFail(FailingTest.java:14)
          at chs.FailingTest.testFail(FailingTest.java:14)
          at chs.FailingTest.testFail(FailingTest.java:14) ....
```

I guess xslt need to trim and skip the large error message.  What is the possible fix?

//Temporary fix: Skip such large text from result html
edit needed in junit-xslt files

```
<xsl:template name="br-replace">
    <xsl:param name="word"/>
    <xsl:if test="string-length($word)  &lt; 31024 "> //very large size here causes stackoverflow
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($word, '&#xa;')">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($word, '&#xa;')"/>
        <br/>
        <xsl:call-template name="br-replace">
          <xsl:with-param name="word" select="substring-after($word, '&#xa;')"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$word"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Final fix: After seeing the answers below, I checked ant development site. 
The SVN has new xslt : http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/ant/core/trunk/src/etc/junit-frames-xalan1.xsl?view=co&content-type=text%2Fplain , which updated the template to be  as below

```
<xsl:template name="br-replace">
    <xsl:param name="word"/>
    <xsl:param name="br"><br/></xsl:param>
    <xsl:value-of select='stringutils:replace(string($word),"&#xA;",$br)'/>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the code to XSLT 2.0:

```
<xsl:template name="br-replace">
    <xsl:param name="word"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="tokenize($word, '&#xa;')">
      <xsl:if test="position() != 1"><br/></xsl:if>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Alternatively, run the existing code using Saxon as the XSLT processor. Saxon implements tail-call optimization, which turns this recursive template into an ordinary loop.

Comment: That gave a clue to see new br-replace in svn : http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/ant/core/trunk/src/etc/junit-frames-xalan1.xsl?view=co&content-type=text%2Fplain - Using this as answer

Answer (score 1):

```
   public void testFail() {
        testFail();// gives stackoverflow- result xml is now a large document
    }
```

This method is calling itself .... without an exit point